# Как запрограммировать переход по ссылке при нажатии на текст?

Tags: html

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  color: teal;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://novostivmire.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81.jpg");
}
```

```html
<h1>Космоинфо</h1>
<h3>Погрузись в космос вместе с нами!</h3>
<h1>
  <pre>Новости   Вопросы   Основная   Статьи   Астрофото   Видео</pre>
</h1>
```

Верстаю свою первую нормальную веб-страницу.
В самом низу страницы есть меню.
Но возникли затруднения. Мне надо, чтобы при щелчке на них я переходил по ссылке.

Можете рассказать и показать, как это делается?

Comment: дак и сделайте текст ссылками? `<h1><a href="/news">Новости</a> ....`

Comment: я так сам могу сделать. Но мне надо, чтобы надписи были белые

Comment: ну так дайте цвет какой нужно
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: *...мне надо, чтобы надписи были белые* - [изучайте css](http://htmlbook.ru/content/svoystva-ssylok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `<a href="ссылка">Текст ссылки</a>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>
     Космоинфо
    </title>
    <body>
        <style>
         h1{text-align:center;color:white;}
            h3{text-align:center;color:white;}
            a{color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;}
            h2{color:teal;}
            body{background-image:url("https://novostivmire.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81.jpg");}
        </style>
        </style>
     <h1>Космоинфо</h1>
        <h3>Погрузись в космос вместе с нами!</h3>
        <h1><pre><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Новости</a>   Вопросы   Основная   Статьи   Астрофото   Видео</pre></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```